# unable to login admin panel getting as invalid credentials in php

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

Unable to login to admin panel getting error message as invalid credentials after entering correct credentials also.Here is my code

index.php:

```
 <form method="post" action="login_model.php">
    <input type="text" class="text" placeholder="E-mail address" name="admin_email" id="admin_email">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="admin_password" id="admin_password">
    <div class="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Login"></div>
    <ul class="new">
        <li class="new_left"><p><a href="forgetpassword.html">Forgot Password ?</a></p></li>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </ul>
</form>
```

login_model.php :

```
 $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or      die(mysql_error());
 $db = mysql_select_db("dance", $connection);
 $name = $_POST["admin_email"];
 $password = $_POST["admin_password"];
 if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM admin_login where admin_email= '$name' AND 
    admin_password= '$password' ";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $rows=mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($rows==1){
       session_start();
       $_SESSION['username'] = "$email";
       header("Location:voterslist.php");
    } else {
       echo "Invalid Username or Password";
    }
 }
```

Comment: Your code is exploitable, escape data before using it in a query + mysql is deprecated use mysqli instead

Comment: There could be several errors. e.g. at least a `'` or `\\` in the password can break the query.  Or the record exists less or more than once. And yes you should look into mysqli or pdo and use named parameters.